How to open a houdini flipbook by houdini engine
I have an HDA that contains a Python script for creating a flipbook preview in Houdini Core. Here's the script that works well within Houdini:
def onClick():
    cur = hou.ui.curDesktop()
    sceneViewer = hou.paneTabType.SceneViewer
    scene = cur.paneTabOfType(sceneViewer)
    scene.flipbookSettings().stash()
    option = scene.flipbookSettings()
    
    option.useResolution(1)
    option.resolution((1080, 720))
    scene.flipbook(scene.curViewport(), option)

The button's callback in the HDA is set to: exec(hou.pwd().parm('python').eval()); onClick();
However, when I try to use this HDA in Unreal Engine with Houdini Engine, I cannot open the flipbook preview when passing a button parameter from Unreal to Houdini Engine.  There's nothing happen.
Is there anyone known how to create a flipbook or a similar preview in Unreal Engine using Houdini Engine? I'm looking for a way to visualize the progress or status of my simulations directly in Unreal when they are being processed by the Houdini Engine plugin.

I export the output as a .bgeo file and use gplay to load the sequence temporarily. But is there any method to get a preview without output?
